# rgba not working in javascript if else

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have this code if else in javascript and it works perfectly fine with ordinary colors like green, red, etc but not in rgba.. please help me. This is my snippet

```
<div id="div" onclick="color()" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:2px solid black; background-color:rgba(0, 255, 51, 0.33)"></div>

<script>
function color(){
    if(document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor == "rgba(0, 255, 51, 0.33)"){
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor="rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.33)";
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this?

Comment: Well you could just remove the `if` or is there more to the function than this?

Comment: Do a little debugging. See what `console.log(document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor)` shows you.

Comment: the color doesnt change

Comment: As @ExplosionPills suggests - try removing the `if` statement. Does the color change when you do that (and you call the `color()` fuction...)?

Comment: oh.. it actually change in firefox but not in chrome.. please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome changes the `rgba` value to `rgba(0, 255, 51, 0.329412)`, so you're not getting a match in your `if` statement.

You'll have a much easier time if you use classes instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/zVYKS/

```
#div {
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    border:2px solid black;
}
.on {
    background-color:rgba(0, 255, 51, 0.33);
}
.off {
    background-color:rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.33);
}
```

---

```
<div id="div" onclick="color()" class="on"></div>

<script>
function color(){
    var d = document.getElementById("div");
    if (d.classList.contains("on")) {
        d.classList.add("off");
        d.classList.remove("on");
    } else {
        d.classList.add("on");
        d.classList.remove("off");
    }
}
</script>
```